# Kotlin / Android app - changing view elements from outside Activity

Tags: android, design-patterns, kotlin

I am using kotlin lang to create my Android app.

I wanted to create an object (singleton) that would specialise in modyfying my main activity's view components dynamically (like buttons etc) and would be used by my main activity itself.

Some problems arose. First of all, the object is (of course) not Activity type, so  I cannot use for example findViewById and other Activity's functions etc. I tried to resolve this by passing main Activity by object's constructor, but it's not allowed - since objects cannot have their constructors.

Additionally I am not sure, if this app design is acceptable according to at least good practices. If not really - what design pattern should I use to separate logic of how to change my layouts from the code that only will modify view elements?

Thank you in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Observers, observables to do it. RxJava/RxAndroid/RxKotlin

or you can use Otto or greenbus for event sending/catching from a singleton class.

RxKotlin example.

UserManager.kt

```
    @Singleton
    class UserManager(private val rxBus : RxBus){

    fun sendX(){
    rxBus.send(EventX())
    }
```

on Main activity

MainActivity.kt

```
class MainActivity : AppCompat ....

onCreate(...){


rxBus.toObservable()
                                   .applySchedulers()
                                   .subscribe({ event ->
                                                  if (event is EventX)
                                                  {
                                                      //do something here.
                                                  }
                                              })
                          )
}
```

rxBus.kt

```
@Singleton
class RxBus
{
    private val _bus = PublishSubject.create<Any>()

    fun send(o: Any)
    {
        _bus.onNext(o)
    }

    fun toObservable(): Observable<Any>
    {
        return _bus
    }

    fun hasObservers(): Boolean
    {
        return _bus.hasObservers()
    }
}
```

Otto is a good and easy to use library from square, but jake warthon said don't use it on kotlin go with rxjava. i don't remember why.

Comment: Thank you for the hints. :)